# Rails plugin to separate markup and logic, like Wicket or Effigy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, components

I need a Rails plugin that gives you the chance to purely separate HTML and any logic in your views. Views should be classes reading the separate markup and replacing it with dynamic content where needed.
Basically [Effigy](https://github.com/jferris/effigy) from github does this.
I am looking for something like [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), but on the Rails base.

I can remember seeing a plugin from a Rails enterprise that does this. In my memory, it was better and seemed more mature than Effigy. But I forgot its name. It was something like "luxurious" or "delicious"; does anyone know what I am talking about? The plugin was created in a US Rails enterprise.
Any other alternatives would be much appreciated.
I feel that Effigy is almost OK, but it's hard to find tutorials or people using it properly, so I question its the maturity.
Well, if nothing comes up, I will go ahead with [Effigy](https://github.com/jferris/effigy) for now.

Comment: +1:  I'd be very interested in this as well.  No idea, but I'll watch for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys, I think I finally found what I was talking about.
The plugin is called ["Erector"](http://erector.rubyforge.org/)

The thing that I like about it, is that views are finally plain ruby objects and you can do everything you can usually do in ruby. I found couple of blogposts:
https://github.com/erector/erector

Why I always liked this idea you can easily see in [this blogpost](http://railsindirection.blogspot.com/2009/05/erector-ruby-crud-views.html)
I want to thank the creators for this.